# Creating application in eclipse PyDev gives the following error

Tags: mysql, django, pydev

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/Users/chinmayghag/Documents/workspace/lm_stats_site/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/chinmayghag/tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/chinmayghag/tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/chinmayghag/tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/chinmayghag/tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/chinmayghag/tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/chinmayghag/tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 41, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/Users/chinmayghag/tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 139, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/chinmayghag/tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/chinmayghag/tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/chinmayghag/tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/chinmayghag/tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/chinmayghag/tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/chinmayghag/tutorial/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
Finished "/Users/chinmayghag/Documents/workspace/lm_stats_site/manage.py startapp lmstats" execution.
```

I have tried almost all possible solution available but I am still not able to solve this issue. I am using Mac OS(Yosemite).

Comment: Attempting to remove the obvious: Have you installed MySQLdb?

Comment: can you provide me useful links about how to go about in it please

Comment: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#installation

Comment: Which are these "possible solutions" you have tried? Please edit your question and give a few examples...

Comment: When you follow the instructions in bernie's comment; make sure you are installing the package in your [`/tutoarial/env` python environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) (rather than globally).

Comment: I am not getting any kind of error when I try to import mysqldb using terminal but I dont know what way can I use the same in eclipse(pydev) which gives me following error